# Inject or Bind "Alias" in an ServiceStack entity

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

I have 3 tables which contains same set of columns. Do i need to create 3 entities for all the DB tables? Is there a way to avoid creating 3 entities and have only one in ServiceStack?

Yes there is one way of doing it like below

```
List<EntityA> list = db.SqlList<EntityA>("SELECT COL_A,COL_B FROM TableA");
```

**Entity** without ***Alias*** on Class

```
public class EntityA
{
    [Alias("COL_A")]
    public string ColumnA { get; set; }
    [Alias("COL_B")]
    public string ColumnB { get; set; }
}
```

in this way i can change the table name(***TableA/TableB/TableC***) provided in the **Query**
but I want something like injecting / passing the alias while retrieving the results from the database. I am not sure if this is possible with service stack

**Edited**
Let me rephrase the question Instead of returning differenct objects like EntityTableA/EntityTableB/EntityTableC as Result i want

```
return db.Select<GenericEntity>(w => w.OrderBy(o => o.ColumnA));
```

the **GenericEntity** can be any tables result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use inheritance to reduce boilerplate:

```
public class EntityBase
{
    [Alias("COL_A")]
    public string ColumnA { get; set; }
    [Alias("COL_B")]
    public string ColumnB { get; set; }
}
```

Then inherit properties from the shared entity, e.g:

```
public class TableA : EntityBase {}
public class TableB : EntityBase {}
```

Then query it as normal:

```
var results = db.Select<TableA>(q => ColumnA == "A");
```

Otherwise yeah the using any of the raw SQL API's will work as well.

#### Modifying SqlExpression

You can also override the SqlExpression FromExpression to include your own table, e.g:

```
var q = db.From<GenericEntity>().OrderBy(o => o.ColumnA);
q.From("TableA");
List<GenericEntity> results = db.Select(q);
```

This will change the SQL to SELECT from `TableA` instead.

Comment: This is good idea so that i don't have to declare/define properties in all the classes but i am actually looking for something like.  
Instead of returning differenct objects like EntityTableA/EntityTableB/EntityTableC as Result i want    return db.Select<GenericEntity>(w => w.OrderBy(o => o.ColumnA));
the GenericEntity can be any tables result

Comment: @Shil Added example that shows how to override the typed SqlExpression with a custom table name.

Comment: Thanks mythz for giving me the clue the following code i used     db.Select<GenericEntity>(w => w.Where(whereExperssion).OrderBy(o => o.ColumnA).From("TableA"));